# Error in row_number() after group_by() and unnest_tokens()

Tags: r, tidytext

I am trying to mutate row numbers after tokenizing within a group_by block and get an error:
Error: Can't recycle input of size 73422 to size 37055.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(janeaustenr)

all_sentences <- austen_books() %>%
  group_by(book) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  mutate(s_number = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

after ungrouping and regrouping its o.k.

```
all_sentences <- austen_books() %>%
  group_by(book) %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(book) %>%
  mutate(s_number = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But it seems awkward
please advise

Comment: Be sure to check out the `collapse` argument for `unnest_tokens()` to see which option you want in the case of a token like sentences or n-grams that may span multiple lines and/or groups. You may want to nest the data by your grouping available to avoid getting tokens that combine text from your different groups.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, suppose should be FALSE. Error still exists with a different size: Error: Can't recycle input of size 73422 to size 87906. While the workaround in the answer is more elegant, I still wonder why the error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your group_by to after the `unnest_tokens` statement. Like this:

```
all_sentences <- austen_books() %>%
  unnest_tokens(sentence, text, token = "sentences") %>%
  group_by(book) %>%
  mutate(s_number = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```